# PHP/HTML Form Display

Tags: php, html

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? The code runs fine, but the result that outputs is weird. It is giving me an extra column.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$serverName = "server\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"mine");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if($conn === FALSE){
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = 'SELECT id, name, age FROM names';
$records = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Heath Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>


    <?php
    while ($employee = sqlsrv_fetch_array($records, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$employee['id']."<td>";
        echo "<td>".$employee['name']."<td>";
        echo "<td>".$employee['age']."<td>";
        echo "<tr>";

    }
    ?>

    </table>
</body>
```

Here is the rersult:
[image]

Why the extra column?

Comment: close `<td>` tags properly

Comment: Watch your closing tags `</td>` and `</tr>` !!

Comment: OMG!!!  I totally missed that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to terminate the tags

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$employee['id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$employee['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$employee['age']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$serverName = "server\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"mine");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if($conn === FALSE)
{
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = 'SELECT id, name, age FROM names';
$records = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Heath Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>


<?php
while ($employee = sqlsrv_fetch_array($records, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$employee['id']."<td>";
    echo "<td>".$employee['name']."<td>";
    echo "<td>".$employee['age']."<td>";
    echo "<tr>";

}
?>

</table>
```